# How to do credit card payments in the web site in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway

I know this question has repeated in stackoverflow. But i'm posting this, just to get an advice as i have messed up all the things about this topic and i don't have any correct idea of what i'm doing.Please guide me.I will be very grateful. I'm just a beginner to programming. I'm developing a web site, Which can post advertisements by customers about vehicles. and whenever a customer posted a ad, if he/she needs to make that posted advertisement to be appear at the top of the website, he/she can pay a fixed amount of money and make that advertisement the top ad. So for this task i need to ad a payment gateway which can accept credit card payments.

I have created a sandbox account in paypal developer site and also have upgraded it to paypal pro account. and also i watched so many tutorials on this, but now i have messed up with all those tutorial information and i don't have correct idea about how to do this. In some tutorials there linking the paypal account with paypal manager etc. I'm messed up with all these things and i don't know what purpose they are creating this paypal manager etc. According to my knowledge i think, To accept credit card details paypal payment pro account is used. So please anyone can give me a guide to how to begin to do this task. and if anyone can please show me a any step by step tutorial to achieve this task. 
please guide me.
I will be very grateful for any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Paypal to validate payment, normally you just have to use the PayPal API.
Official documentation is good : [Paypal SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/)

Hope it can helps you.

EDIT : [Here, examples in PHP, very simple.](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/)